# Drawing function but only on a certain screen/page (actionscript3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drawing

How do I make a drawing function to function only on one page/screen of an app? For example, the drawing function should only happens on page 15. What should I do in order for the "drawing"/drawing function to not be stuck on the screen when it goes to other pages? (I am trying to do a prototype) Thanks.

Here is the drawing function code that I am using :

```
var Line:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(Line);
Line.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, 1 );

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown1);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp1);

function mouseDown1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Line.graphics.moveTo(e.stageX, e.stageY);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove1);
}

function mouseMove1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Line.graphics.lineTo(e.stageX, e.stageY);
}

function mouseUp1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw something in your `stage`, you have added some `MouseEvent` listeners to your `stage`, so to stop drawing, you have simply to remove these listeners and clear your `Graphics` object, if you need of course, like this :

```
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown1)
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp1);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove1);

Line.graphics.clear();
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Flash has no concept of pages. Whatever you have decided is a "page" will be the same place that you will need to clear the drawing. For instance, if you are using frames like pages, then when you change the frame (`gotoAndStop()`, etc) your should clear the graphics.

To clear the graphics you can remove the `Line` object (either with `removeChild()` or a keyframe on the timeline), or you could use `Line.graphics.clear()`.